# Where is the missing Teensie?

Tags: rayman-fiesta-run

In *Rayman Fiesta Run* I've managed to unlock each Invaded mode, and gotten 4 Teensies from each level. However, I'm still left with one missing node to open up the last skull level[image]

I've been over the map again and again, and I don't appear to be missing a Teensie from any level. I haven't collected 100 Lums from each of the Invaded levels, but I've definitely got all the Teensies. Is there something I'm missing, or is the last node opened up by getting 100 Lums on each of the Invaded levels?

Comment: Why was this down voted? I mean it has some poor qualities, but I can fix those so it has a better feel to it.

Comment: @ShadowZorgon I'm guessing because 3 answers to it have been deleted. People tend to be vengeful when their answer is deleted.

Comment: Ah. That makes a lot of sense.